# No network available on Supermicro server

Tags: networking, supermicro

I recently acquired a second heand Supermicro 2027GR-TRF with a Super X9DRG-HF motherboard. I can't access the network and I don't understand why. Both RJ45 ports are blinking green steadily.

Here what I tried to do:

- Bios has been updated and restored to optimized default configuration
- I tested the RJ45 straight through wire
- I tested different ports on the switch that are working (Netgear prosafe)

The `dmesg` doesn't output anything relevant. Same with the commands `lshw -class network` and `lspci | grep -i 'network|ethernet'`.

The only good news is that I see both ports using the command `dmidecode --type 8`.

I don't know where to go from there, I tried to see if something in particular in the BIOS was disabled and didn't find anything relevant. I search the web for equivalent issues without success until now. If anyone would have pointers on what's wrong or other obvious tests I've missed to perform would be a great start.

I should mentioned that I have another server with same features that works fine and I didn't find discrepancies in the configuration (but, once again I may have missed something obvious).

Thanks a lot for your help and I hope my post is clear enough,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A note on [this motherboard's web page](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C600/X9DRG-HF.cfm) indicates that the onboard Intel NICs only work when the motherboard has two CPUs installed. This is one of the stranger compatibility issues I have ever heard, but there it is.

You should ensure that you are using a recent Linux distribution with the latest available kernel in that distribution.

Comment: Thanks so much, I missed that completely. With a second CPU, it works right away.